# How to merge/concat/join two or more Pandas DataFrames indexed by datetime and filling gaps with NaN

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Why my question is different to others with the same topic, merge/concat/join?

I'm trying to merge 2 Pandas data frames. Both of them indexed by timestamps but different dates. I would like to merge both without repeating values and filling gaps with NaN.

Some of the Frames have different length.

I have 2 data frames like below:

```
           c1b28dc
date    
2016-02-01  291
2016-02-01  159
2016-02-02  322
2016-02-03  31
2016-02-10  8
```

```
            956773a
date    
2016-02-01  350
2016-02-01  27
2016-02-02  11
2016-02-02  8
2016-02-02  25
```

But when I merged them I got:

```
           c1b28dc         956773a
date        
2016-02-01  291.0          350.0
2016-02-01  291.0          27.0
2016-02-01  159.0          350.0
2016-02-01  159.0          27.0
2016-02-02  322.0          11.0
2016-02-02  322.0          8.0
2016-02-02  322.0          25.0
```

And What I want is:

```
           c1b28dc         956773a
date        
2016-02-01  291.0          350.0
2016-02-01  159.0          27.0
2016-02-02  322.0          11.0
2016-02-02  NaN            8.0
2016-02-02  NaN            25.0
2016-02-03  31             NaN
2016-02-10  8              NaN
```

I am trying different method with concat, join and merge, but I got no improvement.

```
df1.merge(df2, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)

pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)

df1.join(df2)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assign a new key with `cumcount` here to help `merge`

```
df1=df1.assign(key=df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount()).reset_index()
df2=df2.assign(key=df2.groupby(level=0).cumcount()).reset_index()
df=df1.merge(df2,how='right')
# you can drop the columns by df=df.drop('key',1)
         date  c1b28dc  key  956773a
0  2016-02-01    291.0    0      350
1  2016-02-01    159.0    1       27
2  2016-02-02    322.0    0       11
3  2016-02-02      NaN    1        8
4  2016-02-02      NaN    2       25
```

---

Update

```
df1.merge(df2,how='outer').sort_values('date').drop('key',1)
        date  c1b28dc  956773a
0 2016-02-01    291.0    350.0
1 2016-02-01    159.0     27.0
2 2016-02-02    322.0     11.0
5 2016-02-02      NaN      8.0
6 2016-02-02      NaN     25.0
3 2016-02-03     31.0      NaN
4 2016-02-10      8.0      NaN
```

Comment: I wrote the same you gave me but I got different result. Until `row[2]`, all good, but in `row[3]` I get the `date: 2016-02-03` instead of `date: 2016-02-02` again

Comment: @SalvadorVigo I am not sure what happen here, I can provide my data input , maybe you can try it ?

Comment: I think I know the problem. in your input the index are strings instead datetime objects. In my case they are datetime types

Comment: @SalvadorVigo even it is datetime , still work . let me try

Comment: @SalvadorVigo yep , it yield the same output

Comment: @SalvadorVigo also I am no sure whether this solve your problem ,  if so , would you like accept and upvote ?

Comment: The thing is when I use a simple input as you describe it works. But when I try in my frame, it doesn't work. I will keep trying. Thanks for the input if it will work I'll let you know

Comment: @SalvadorVigo just convert your datetime to str also make sure that is date only dose not include time if so you need make sure both df have the same format of date

Comment: I already edit my Question. There can you see the complete output I want to get. And with your example I miss the last two values I already add. What do you think?

Comment: @SalvadorVigo check the update , it is just outer merge

Comment: Now We are talking!! Nice job